# How to decode this json object data in java

Tags: java, json

I got this json object data which is

```json
{
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
    "first_name": "Janet",
    "last_name": "Weaver",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
  },
  "ad": {
    "company": "StatusCode Weekly",
    "url": "http://statuscode.org/",
    "text": "A weekly newsletter  focusing on software development, infrastructure, the server, performance, and the stack end of things."
  }
}
```

I want to parse json which i want to print output email in object...I use org.simple.json library .

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("curl -s -S https://reqres.in/api/users/2");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

String result = br.readLine();
Object obj=JSONValue.parse(result);
```

How do I println email data via data -> email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just cast the value to `JSONObject` and use `JSONObject` API further for printing

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(result);
    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("data");
    String email= (String) data.get("email");
    System.out.println("Email= " + email);
```

Answer (score 1):

According the java doc, `JSONValue.parse` returns

> Instance of the following: org.json.simple.JSONObject, org.json.simple.JSONArray, java.lang.String, java.lang.Number, java.lang.Boolean, null

In your case it should be a `JSONObject`,so you can cast it to a `JSONObject` and use method in JSONObject to retrive email.

```
Object obj=JSONValue.parse(result);
JSONObject jsonObject=(JSONObject)obj;
JSONObject data=(JSONObject)jsonObject.get("data");
String email= (String)data.get("email");
```

In recent version `JSONObject` has been deprecated, use `JsonObject` instead, which don't bother using so many casting.

Answer (score 0):

Download dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813
and Use below code -

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class TestJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec("curl -s -S https://reqres.in/api/users/2");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String result = br.readLine();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
    String email = obj.getJSONObject("data").getString("email");
    System.out.println(email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ObjectMapper can also be used:

use the pom to download the dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Code:-

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    public class HelloWorld{
    
         public static void main(String []args){
            String dataJson = "{\"data\":{\"id\":2,\"email\":\"janet.weaver@reqres.in\",\"first_name\":\"Janet\",\"last_name\":\"Weaver\",\"avatar\":\"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg\"},\"ad\":{\"company\":\"StatusCode Weekly\",\"url\":\"http://statuscode.org/\",\"text\":\"A weekly newsletter\n" + 
                    "focusing on software development, infrastructure, the server,\n" + 
                    "performance, and the stack end of things.\"}}";
            
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                A a = objectMapper.readValue(dataJson, A.class);
    
                System.out.println("email  = " + a.data.email);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
    }
    
    
    class A{
        B data;
    }
    class B{
        int id;
        String email;
        String first_name;
        String last_name;
        String avatar;
        String ad;
        String url;
        String text;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in general case you have to use some `JSON` parser framework like [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson). But in case you have to find **only one value** and do not care about `json` validation or other aspects, then you could use simple `RegExp`:

```
public static String getEmail(String json) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"email\"\\s*:\\s*\"(?<email>[^\"]+)\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json);
    return matcher.find() ? matcher.group("email") : null;
}
```

or event simplier `str.indexOf()`:

```
public static String getEmail(String json) {
    int pos = json.indexOf("\"email\"");
    pos = pos == -1 ? pos : json.indexOf('"', pos + 7);
    return pos == -1 ? null : json.substring(pos + 1, json.indexOf('"', pos + 1));
}
```